# Is there a simulation framework for django applications? What are the good practices to write one?

Tags: python, django, testing, statistics, simulation

So, I have an idea.

Suppose you have classic application that consists of several classes of users and some data they working with. Let's say that it is Passengers, Drivers and Dispatchers (as in taxi). Passengers create orders, Dispatchers assign orders to Drivers and Drivers are executing orders,  Passengers write reviews about Drivers, Dispatchers use these reviews in their dispatching scheme and so on.

Lets say that you have such system, that incorporates few dozens of dispatchers, few hundreds of drivers and thousands of passengers.

As time goes by, new dispatchers are getting hired, some of them are sacked, drivers come and go, and, as always, there are loyal customers and new customers as well.

So, my question is — how to simulate such system? I want to have a tool that allows me to use my current django application, its models and methods, and fill it with users, data and actions created with different patterns.

I see it like a independent framework (sorta like unittest frameworks and data generation framework) that can attach itself to any application, describe patterns for users and then run it in continuous manner.

It might be useful for:

- better logic testing of product
- simulating reallife experiments ("what if there is Driver, who screws a lot of orders")
- more intelligent load testing system (which really tests reallife scenarios, including "whatif" situations)
- creating reallife-like data to test statistic software

Is there any preexisting solutions? Do you have any suggestions for me if I decide to create one?

Comment: Why not do this within the unit testing framework?

Comment: Because unittests are something that non-persistent. "Simulation" means to run it continuously, preserving data that is being created and monitoring how system evolves. For example, after some time of simulation (that was sped up of course), you might see that your database size (or count of sql queries) grows exponentially and consider optimizations.

Comment: this is a great question for django applications that deal with real world entities.  i am looking to do something very similar.  i see that you have no selected answer here - did you ever get anywhere with this?  i'm interested in what you learned.

Comment: no, i did not. I still think that this is a good idea though. Looking back into my experience in that project (which is quite large real world system) to have such playground would be very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You have a very specific task for common solution. By my opinion, you must use any data generators (ex. [django-dilla](http://aerosol.github.com/django-dilla/), [django-mockups](https://github.com/sorl/django-mockups), [django-milkman](https://github.com/ccollins/milkman)), task queue ([celery](http://celeryproject.org/), rabbitmq) and write a custom backend.

The problem hasn't universal answers.

Comment: Problem might not have universal solution, but it has some universal aspects. For example every particular simulation case has repetition rate. In every simulated system owner wants to see how system grows (or shrinks) over time with this particular set of constants (and how grow pattern changes with changing of constants). In every simulation you want to measure load (and how it changes when you change system). Basically, my idea is about blackbox-style testing of systems where you write tests which describes near to real-life cases and see what it does to your system.

Comment: Basically, data doesn't matter. It's process that matters. So data generators almost irrelevant. What is needed is some abstract layer that allows you to describe your application models workflow, how they are being registered, how they change, how they act (in time). Also, this framework that I dream of helps with describing different  roles like LazyDriver, VeryGoodDriver, AverageDriver (or BadBehavingPassenger) and lets me change proportions of them. It might even emulate their actions via existing django views.